# how to make question number slider in flutter?

Tags: flutter, slider

we have a slider to select the question number, like the picture below.

[image]

Which tool should I use to make it?
Please tell me the steps of making it in general, I will find the details of the code myself.

Comment: Try with stepper widget

Answer (score 0):

You can use Stepper Class Widget official by Flutter doc and also use a custom package by the flutter community

[Stepper Package](https://pub.dev/packages/im_stepper)

[Stepper Class Widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Stepper-class.html#:%7E:text=A%20material%20stepper%20widget%20that,widget%20is%20a%20flexible%20wrapper.)

Comment: Stepper does not have the necessary capacity, including shadow and line size change

Answer (score 0):

Use this package `im_stepper: ^1.0.1+1`

```
import 'stepper.dart';


NumberStepper(
    numbers:[
        1,
        2,
        3,
        4,
    ]
),
```

[image]

Comment: Stepper does not have the necessary capacity, including shadow and line size change